# Load available library version for use in COM library

Tags: c#, logging, dll, com

So I'm writing a C# library that will be interfaced with through COM.  This library uses **log4net** for logging purposes.  Now this COM library may have to load different versions of log4net depending on the installed version of the host application so I'm trying to make it so that it will load whatever version of log4net is available in it's installed directory.  Now I'm familiar with using BindingRedirects but I've never used them in a library before and so wouldn't know how.  Looking up 'related' questions on StackOverflow I've come across solutions for controlling the loading of the assembly.  Here is an example of what I've tried.

```
Assembly assembly = null;

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    string name = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;

    if (name.Equals("log4net"))
    {
        return assembly;
    }
    return null;
};

assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("log4net.dll");
```

And edited the csproj so that no specific version is referenced.

```
<Reference Include="log4net">
  <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.1.2.10\lib\2.0\log4net.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

But not matter what I do (I've tried several variations of the code above) I get this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have a feeling that what I'm trying to accomplish here is possible but I'm just going about it the wrong way.  I would also settle for a way to use an app.config file tailored specifically to the library if I can apply BindingRedirects that way.  I would appreciate any advice anyone has on this whether good or bad.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone is stuck with the same problem I have a workaround that worked for me.  So I decided to use the Fody weaver Costura https://github.com/Fody/Costura to just embedded log4net in my COM dll.  In my FodyWeavers.xml I used the configuration below to only include log4net as a merged assembly.

```
<Costura>
    <IncludeAssemblies>
      log4net
    </IncludeAssemblies>
</Costura>
```

I'd still really like to see if it's possible to dynamically load any version of the assembly (log4net) but for now the solution above is meeting my needs.